# find duplicate row in the same table and mark them in sql

Tags: sql

I have table 'workadress' and it contain 6 columns:
work_ref,work_street ,work_zip,workTN,...

I want to find duplicate rows in the same table depending on:

If (work_street, work_zip) are duplicate together, then you should look at workTN. If it is the same then put value ' ok ', but if workTN is not the same, put 'not ok'. How can I do it with SQL?

Result like:

[image: see the image]

Comment: What have you tried?  What is your table structure?  What RDMBS are you using?  Have you tried row_number  look that up

Comment: SELECT work_ref, name, work_street, work_zip,,workTN from workadress    no i donot try i want result like this

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think just a simple group by and count should be enough to do the job like so:

```
select 
  t.*, 
  case when dups.dups = 1 then 'OK' else 'not OK' end
from my_table t
join (
  select work_street, work_zip, count(distinct workTN) dups
  from my_table
  group by work_street, work_zip 
) dups on dups.work_street = t.work_street amd dups.work_zip = t.work_zip
```

Comment: Ptrov   what i should  to do if i want to check in another table 'ORG' that conatin  work_ref if this adress used(work_street, work_zip) i should create a new column used='y' else ''  should i use left join or exist !

Comment: Not sure I fully understand the use case but seems like a left join would do like:

`select 
  t.*, 
  case when dups.dups = 1 then 'OK' else 'not OK' end
from my_table t
join (
  select work_street, work_zip, count(distinct workTN) dups
  from my_table
  left join another_table on ....
  group by work_street, work_zip 
) dups on dups.work_street = t.work_street amd dups.work_zip = t.work_zip`

Sorry, not sure how to make it better formatted

Comment: i am thanks full i get it through add left join   and use case up

Answer (score 1):

You can use window functions:

```
select t.*,
       (case when min(workTn) over (partition by work_street, work_zip) =
                  max(workTn) over (partition by work_street, work_zip)
             then 'ok' else 'not ok'
        end) as result
from t;
```